# How can I remove the HTML document`s content only leaving a chosen part of the document with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple quiz making website for my portfolio. There are two buttons for adding questions and answers, when you add questions and answers underneath the fieldset containing the "add question/answer" buttons pops up a preview of the quiz you`ve made. After you add some questions and answers you can press a "create" button on the bottom of the page. I want to add an eventListener to that button so that when it is pressed everything besides the "preview" fieldset is cleared from the document. Is there an easier way than removing all elements with the body.removeChild()?

Thanks for any replies this recieves. I am new to stackoverflow so I apologize if a break an unwritten rule with the way I structured my question.

The code in question:

```
<body id="quiz-body">
    <h1>Let`s make a quiz</h1>
    <form id="quiz-form">
        <fieldset class="quiz-type" id="quiz-type">
            <label>Will this quiz be anonymous:</label>
            <label for="anonymous-quiz"
            ><input
              id="anonymous-quiz"
              type="radio"
              name="quiz-type"
              class="inline"
              value="anonymous"
              checked
            />
            Yes, do not require participant name.</label>
            <label for="non-anonymous-quiz"
              ><input
                id="non-anonymous-quiz"
                type="radio"
                name="quiz-type"
                class="inline"
                value="non-anonymous"
              />
              No, do require participant name.</label
            >

            </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <label>Add a question:</label>
            <input type="text" id="question-input">
            <button type="button" id="add-question" class="add__Question"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                add
                </span></button>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="answersDisplay" class="answers__Display">
            <p id="added-question"></p>
            <label>Add answer:</label>
            <input type="text" id="answer">
            <label for="true">
            <input  class="check" id="true-answer" type="radio" name="answer-value" value="true" checked>True</label>
            <label for="false">
                <input class="check" id="false-answer" type="radio" name="answer-value" value="false">False</label>
            <button type="button" id="add-answer" class="add__Answer"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            add
            </span></button>
        </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
    <div id="preview-container">
        <h2>Preview</h2>
        <fieldset id="preview">
            <input type="text" id="name-input" placeholder="Please enter your name">
        </fieldset>
    </label>
    </div>
    <button id="create-quiz">Create</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="quiz.js"></script>
</form>
</body>
```

I wish to remove everything besides the "preview-container" div. I apologise for the monstrosity that this is.

Comment: you can also call `.remove()` on the HTMLElement you meant to remove. Or even just set the `innerHTML` property of the parent element. Do you have any code to show?

Comment: If you can post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would help too!

Comment: In the markup, wrap the elements to remove into an element (ex. `div`), then remove the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the replies everyone. Turns out I hadn`t given the "create" button a type of "button" so nothing really happened when I pressed it. I wrapped everything unneeded in a div and used remove() and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    buttonId.onclick = () => {
      const element = document.getElementById("elementID");
      element.innerHTML = '';
      // or
      element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    <div id='elementID'>
      <span>Hello</span>
      <span>Test</span>
    </div>
    <button id='buttonId'>Remove via innerHTML</button>
```